# If output of \Log::info depens on some options?

Tags: laravel-5

If output of

```
 \Log::info('text');
```

function is dependable on some options ?

in .env I have :

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

and in config/app.php

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
```

Also in config/logging.php I have options(seems default):

```
<?php

use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\SyslogUdpHandler;

return [


    'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['daily'],
        ],

        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],

        'daily' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
            'days' => 14,
        ],

        'slack' => [
            'driver' => 'slack',
            'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
            'username' => 'Laravel Log',
            'emoji' => ':boom:',
            'level' => 'critical',
        ],

        'papertrail' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'level' => 'debug',
            'handler' => SyslogUdpHandler::class,
            'handler_with' => [
                'host' => env('PAPERTRAIL_URL'),
                'port' => env('PAPERTRAIL_PORT'),
            ],
        ],

        'stderr' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
            'formatter' => env('LOG_STDERR_FORMATTER'),
            'with' => [
                'stream' => 'php://stderr',
            ],
        ],

        'syslog' => [
            'driver' => 'syslog',
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],

        'errorlog' => [
            'driver' => 'errorlog',
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],
    ],

];
```

The quesion is that with my options on live server I expected

```
 \Log::info('text');
```

would not log lines, but it writes lines anyway.

I read here 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging
do not see any dependencies.

?
Laravel 5.7

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve i am not getting your question??

Comment: To have log messages only if APP_DEBUG=true. I suppose that must be default. Maybe I confuse something ?